# ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule, typescript 2.3.2, Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

I recently upgraded to node 6, angular 4, typescript 2.3.2 and @angular/cli 1.02. I followed the [Guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update) on how to upgrade @angular/cli.
I'll add my whole package.json down below if there's anything relevant there.
And I get this error:

```
ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
at Object.getNewLineCharacter (C:\development\projects-git\mydoc\static-    web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:9580:20)
at Object.createCompilerHost (C:\development\projects-git\mydoc\static-web\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:66674:26)
at Object.ngcLoader (C:\development\projects-git\mydoc\static-web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:202:31)
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

in the guide I had to update my `main.ts` to this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

My full `package.json` is this:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.1",
    "@ngtools/json-schema": "1.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.0",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mydatepicker": "^1.9.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "^4.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "string-to-json": "^0.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher-nonet": "0.1.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.2"
  }
}
```

This makes it immpossible to build.

Comment: Can you share your AppModule.ts?

Comment: my app.module.ts is a massive class, with all the imported modules, components and services.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3781).
Make sure your node modules have been reinstalled properly :

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm uninstall --save angular-cli && npm uninstall -g angular-cli && npm i --save @angular/cli && npm i -g @angular/cli && npm i
```

Comment: @JanDeDev Did the above approach fix your issue?